# Use web page as (refreshable) wallpaper in iOS 8

Tags: ios, wallpaper

I have a web page where the content changes hourly. I'd like to use this as my iPhone's wallpaper. Is there a way to have the wallpaper update automatically / on a schedule, with the contents of a web page?

I don't want to jailbreak my iPhone to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without a jailbreak due to iOS restrictions.